# Is Sketch affected by accuracy drops or evasion?

Tags: pokemon-series

Let's say an opponent used 6 Sand Attacks/Smokescreens on me and I then attempt to use Sketch; will Sketch be more likely to fail?

What if the opponent used Double Team or Minimize?

Does generation matter?

Answer (score 4):

> Sketch allows the user to learn the target's last move permanently,
> replacing Sketch in the process. It bypasses accuracy checks to always
> hit, unless the target is in the semi-invulnerable turn of a move such
> as Dig or Fly.

[Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sketch_(move)) has a good description of the move and everything you need to know, including when it can be used.